# jQuery's swap method time costly

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, swap

I ran the profiler in firebug and found that the most time costly function being ran in our UI is jQuery's .swap(). I can see that this must be associated with the .css() method.

Here is an image of my profiler:

[image]

Obviously, to improve the speed here I need to cut back on calling .css(), but that is quite the project as I use it to set and correct styling of different elements, which has to be completely dynamic.

Is there a better way to speed this up?

I am using jquery.1.4.2. I haven't been able to move on to 1.4.4 because it breaks quite a few of my scripts for some reason. Would it be be of benefit to extend the swap method from 1.4.4 to 1.4.2? Or would that present more incompatibilities?

What is the swap method and why is it so time costly?

Comment: The CSS stuff was drastically re-written in jQuery 1.4.3, I'd upgrade *before* optimizing anything around that.

Comment: @Nick, thanks. Yeah, tried that but it opened up a can of worms I don't have time for.

Comment: @Dale -If you're going to spend your time, *that's* where I'd spend it, kind of throwing it away by not doing that

Comment: @Nick, Right. The problems I see are mostly with slider widgets. I may need to open a separate question on those if I don't see quick fixes.

Comment: @Dale/Nick To save your argument, I had a look at the code, `.swap()` did not change between 1.4.2 and 1.4.4.

Comment: @Dale - I'd be happy to take a look, please comment here if you do so :)

Comment: @Orbling - `.swap()` is just a piece of the puzzle...what do you think calls it? (and may call it more or less if *it* changes? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see looking at the jQuery UI code, `.swap()` is not called directly by it, the only place in the jQuery framework itself that uses `.swap()` directly are the `.height()` and `.width()` calls when retrieving the computed height/width of an element.

What it does to calculate the sizes when not available directly from the browser is temporarily swaps the style out for the following:

```
cssShow = { position: "absolute", visibility: "hidden", display: "block" };
```

Then performs the usual internal `getWH()` function whilst in that altered style state, and restores.

The partial code borrowed from jQuery:

```
jQuery.each(["height", "width"], function( i, name ) {
    jQuery.cssHooks[ name ] = {
        get: function( elem, computed, extra ) {
            var val;

            if ( computed ) {
                if ( elem.offsetWidth !== 0 ) {
                    val = getWH( elem, name, extra );

                } else {
                    jQuery.swap( elem, cssShow, function() {
                        val = getWH( elem, name, extra );
                    });
                }

                   // etc.
```

jQuery UI uses `height()` and `width()` functions everywhere, so it is little wonder that the `.swap()` function figures highly in the profile.